# scope in inherited model

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a `contact` db table and model. `Employee` model inherits from contact.

If i do **GET employees/** it returns all the contacts.

How should I set up my employee.json if I want to return only the contacts with partnerId = 1?

```
{
  "name": "employee",
  "base": "contact",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "postgresql": {
      "schema": "public",
      "table": "contact"
    }
  },
  "scope": {
    "where": {
      "partnerId": 1
    }
  },
  //...
}
```

Debug says calling GET employees/ makes the following query:

```
SELECT "name", "position", "email", "password", "id"  FROM "public"."contact"   ORDER BY "id"
```

It does not seem that scope is added.

**models/partner.json**

```
{
  "name": "partner",
  // ...
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    // ...
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "contacts": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "contact"
    }
    //...
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the where filter, either in the REST API

```
/employees?filter[where][partnerId]=1
```

or in your Employee.js

```
Employee.find({ where: {partnerId:1} });
```

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Where+filter

Comment: Your first solution is not what I am looking for. The employees endpoint should always return the filtered results. I already tried your 2nd suggestion, but I am getting: Error: Cannot call employee.find(). The find method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource!